# Converting for loop to do while loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, do-while

I need to convert this for loop to a do while:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= input; i = i + 2)
{
    cout << name << " is number " << input << endl;
    total = total + i;
}
cout << endl;
cout << total << endl;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
do
{
    cout << name << " is number " << input << endl;
    i += 2;
    total += i;
} while (i <= input);
cout << endl;
cout << total << endl;
```

It doesn't give the same total value as the for loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you initialize i correctly to zero before the loop?  Are you sure that input can never by negative?

Comment: Yeah I already have all of the variables listed with a value of 0, except for the string name, so I know it can't be that.

Comment: How are you initializing `i` the second time around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add i to the total before incrementing it by 2

So the do..while loop should be like this:

```
do
{
    cout << name << " is number " << input << endl;
    total += i;
    i += 2;
} while (i <= input);
cout << endl;
cout << total << endl;
```

Comment: Glad to be of help.Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it has solved your query.

Comment: It won't do the same if the `i > input` before entering the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between for loop and do-while loop is the fact that:

- For loop executes 0 or more times
- But the do-while loop executes 1 or more times

Example:

```
int input = 100;

//Will never execute as i is bigger than 5
for (int i = input; i<5; ++i)
    cout << i;

//Will execute only one time as i < 5 is checked only
//after first execution
int i = input;
do
{
    cout << i;
} while(i < 5);
```

The way to correctly do you task is:

```
int i = 0;
//if used to prevent first execution
if (i <= input)
{
    do
    {
        cout << name << " is number " << input << endl;
        total = total + i;
        i = i + 2;
    } while(i <= input);
}
```

But for is better to rewrite for loop like

```
for(BEFORE_STATEMENT; FINISH_STATEMENT; ITERATE_STATEMENT)
{
    LOOP_CODE
}
```

as while loop, which will work the same

```
BEFORE_STATEMENT
while(FINISH_STATEMENT)
{
    LOOP_CODE
    ITERATE_STATEMENT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change

```
i += 2;
total += i;
```

to

```
total += i;
i += 2;
```

In your for loop:

```
total = total + i;
```

`i` is equal to 0 at the first iteration. The way you were doing it in the `do - while` loop, `i` was set to 2 before the total addition.

Comment: Damn looks like responding first isn't a criteria for upvotes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so in a previous portion of the code, you need to initialize i in the do...while.

Also, in the do...while, change the order to have total incremented before i is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Corect is

```
do
{
    cout << name << " is number " << input << endl;
    total += i;//swap these lines
    i += 2;//
} while (i <= input);
cout << endl;
cout << total << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

a do while will be exectued at least one time, no mather what the value is i is.
Also you should initialise your i.